# MYSQL query not working with PHP with form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am having trouble with this code. I want to add a row into the table via a HTML form. Here is the code:

EDIT: Here is the HTML code of the form:

```
<form role = "form" action = "aanmaken.php" method = "post" class = "col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-8 col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for "eventName">Naam event: </label>
            <input id = "eventName" class = "form-control" type = "text" name = "eventName" placeholder = "Hier typen">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for "date">Datum: </label>
            <input id = "date" class = "form-control" type = "text" name = "date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for "time">Tijd: </label>
            <input id = "time" class = "form-control" type = "text" name = "time" maxlength="5" placeholder="18:00">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for "max_spelers">Max spelers: </label>
            <input id = "max_spelers" class = "form-control" type = "number" name = "max_spelers" maxlength="2" placeholder="Hier typen">
        </div>
        <input id = "submit" type="submit" value="Aanmaken">
    </form>
```

And the PHP:

```
include 'connect.php';

$eventName = $_POST['eventName'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$aantal_spelers = $_POST['max_spelers'];

$addEvent = "INSERT INTO `dbi286018`.`dutch_delight` (`id`, `eventName`, `date`, `time`, `aantal_spelers`, `current_spelers`) VALUES (NULL, $eventName, $date, $time, $aantal_spelers, \'0\');";

if ($conn->query($addEvent) === TRUE) {
    echo "Je hebt een evenement aangemaakt! Vraag op het forum of op xbox live of mensen je evenement willen bijwonen.";
} 
else {
    echo "Er ging iets fout tijdens het aanmaken van je evenement... probeer het later nog eens, of neem contact op met een van de leiders.";
    mysql_error();
}
```

I keep getting the else statement. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: is `$conn` created in `connect.php`??

Comment: Yes it is! And it's connected

Comment: `mysql_error()`?!? Are you using MySQL? or MySQLi or PDO?

Comment: add connect.php code here too

Comment: You **really** should be using PDO with Prepared statements. You're asking for SQL injection otherwise. Also, we need to see `query()` to know what you're returning. Not only that, but you need to elaborate a bit. What happens in your DB? Do things get entered yet still your script says `FALSE`? Are things not entering the DB? What's going on here...

Comment: Why are you "escaping" single quotes in your query? (`\'0\'`) Why aren't you using prepared statement with bind variables?

Comment: Try change to this: $addEvent = "INSERT INTO `dbi286018`.`dutch_delight` (`id`, `eventName`, `date`, `time`, `aantal_spelers`, `current_spelers`) VALUES (NULL, '$eventName', '$date', '$time', '$aantal_spelers', '0');";

Comment: Thats @KostasMitsarakis !! It worked!! Thank you very much!

Comment: You should try PDO because mysql_* functions are deprecated and PDO is more secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this using PDO because mysql_* functions are deprecated and PDO is more secure:

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
$eventName = $_POST['eventName'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$aantal_spelers = $_POST['max_spelers'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO `dbi286018`.`dutch_delight` (`id`, `eventName`, `date`, `time`, `aantal_spelers`, `current_spelers`) VALUES (:id, :event_name, :date, :time, :aantal_spelers, :current_spelers)";
//Prepare your query
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
//Execute your query binding variables
$stmt->execute(array(':id'=>NULL, ':event_name'=>$eventName, ':date'=>$date, ':time'=>$time, ':aantal_spelers'=>$aantal_spelers, ':current_spelers'=>0));
```

Comment: Works as well! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can find a nice tutorial about PDO here: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html